# Do newel posts come in standard sizes?

Tags: wood, stairs, carpentry, replacement

A newel post in our house needs replacing, since it seems to have been badly abused by the previous owners.

Looking online, I couldn't find any that were the same size and shape as this one. The turned part is 600mm long, and the square at the bottom seems to be 71mm accross.

[image: Newel post 600mm x 71mm]

My questions:

1. Do newel posts come in standard sizes?
2. Does this post sound like it's a standard size?
3. Or would I need to get a new newel post turned up by a carpenter?

Comment: Take your measurements to your local building supply place. Various sizes are available, and of course they can always be made shorter.

Comment: @Jon Custer, make your comment an answer and I will vote for it.

Comment: Define "abuse"—because based on that tiny pic, it looks like that could just be refinished.

Answer (score 1):

The 71mm isn't critical, so something a tad smaller or bigger won't make a lot of difference to the job. The total length of the 600mm part likewise. That could be slightly longer or shorter, without affecting anything.

The best bet, though, would be to take the removed newel post along to a carpenter who would turn one exactly to size, and in whatever wood you prefer, and the cost shouldn't be much different from buying a cheap pine one, which is what most will be - and they won't have that nice profile either.

Comment: A glance online shows similar newel posts in the 80-140 range. Admittedly, I’m in a high cost of living/ high hourly rate zone, but I can’t imagine a craftsman charging anywhere near that low. Ymmv.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - I guess it will depend on whether OP wants that newel post to match u with any other too. Spoil the ship for a halfpennyworth of tar?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that a match wasn't the best bet... I was trying to prepare the OP for sticker shock.